Why does Converter receive Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Binding instead of value?
Fairly simple, I have two bindable properties of type string and I am trying to get true or false upon comparison check using a Converter.
(This is in AppShell, "thisShell" is the name of the root AppShell instance, Route is the property of a ShellSection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.shellsection?view=net-maui-8.0)
Consider the following code:
                     <Label>
                         <Label.Text>
                             <MultiBinding Converter="{converters:StringCompareConverter}">
                                 <Binding Source="{Binding Route}" />
                                 <Binding Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference thisShell}}" />
                             </MultiBinding>
                         </Label.Text>
                     </Label>

What I am doing wrong so that the Converter receives a Binding instance instead of the value I provided ?
Converter code:
public class StringCompareConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object?[] value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       
        if (value[1] != null)
        {

        }

        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object? parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


Maui has multi-bindings? WinAppSdk, which is Maui's Windows backend, absolutely does not, and it encourages using x:Bind with functions.

Yes as you can see in the XAML code I included. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding?view=net-maui-8.0

You're only setting the Source of the Binding, not the Path, maybe that's why?

I am not entirely clear on what Route and what you want from AppShell; the name and code supplied for your converter don't help. But, generally speaking, you should receive values not the Binding themselves that is passed into a MultiBinding. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74319669/how-to-create-markup-extensions-having-bindable-properties/77120315#77120315

@Toto read my answers, if you do not understand something - ask. This should be easy to fix. I know bindings are complicated at first...

When I was starting, two things helped me:
First, writing bindings one by one, testing if they work, and then combining them in complex multi-bindings etc. It was way easier than trying to fix all problems at once.
Second, there is this trick to debug them:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/binding-path?view=net-maui-8.0#debug-complex-paths
So in your case, to fix your problem:

Remove the multi binding.
Bind defining only Source, converting the output to string format {0}.
If it is the correct Type, set Path to the value in that type.
If its not the correct Type, change Source, go to step 2.

Works like a charm.

Using a Source referenced Path in MultiBinding:
<Label x:Name="elementA" Text="Element A" />

<Label>
  <Label.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}:{0}:{1}:">
      <Binding Source="{x:Reference elementA}" Path="Text" />
      <Binding Path="Property1" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </Label.Text>
</Label>

Above property Property1 is from a ViewModel:
public string Property1 => "Property 1";

The above outputs a Label with Text:
:Element A:Property 1:

A converter for a MultiBinding might look like the following:
public class StringCompareConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length > 0 && values.All(i => i is string))
        {
            var items = Enumerable.Range(0, values.Length).Select(i => values[i]).ToArray();

            // Compare the items
            if (/*comparision fails*/)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

Replacing MultiBinding above:
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringCompareConverter}">

outputs a Label with Text True or False depending on the Bindings and the Converter.
