MAUI Converter inline syntax for Generic Types
EDITED: included code snippet
MAUI with XAML being as verbose as it is, just curious if there is a way to write shorter syntax for converters with Generic Types. Take a look at screenshot below. I have to write that much (commented out) to achieve the desired result.
The XAML file will be very long if I use the commented out syntax for every item. And if I make the Converter class for a specific type, then I would have to write/repeat the same class multiple times for different types to achieve shorter XAML.

Current Syntax
<ImageButton.CommandParameter>
    <Binding>
        <Binding.Converter>
            <conv:ItemToMenuItemConverter x:TypeArguments="model:Item" MyView="{x:Reference optionsLayout}" />
        </Binding.Converter>
        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
            <x:Static>helpers:ListOption.TOGGLE</x:Static>
        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
    </Binding>
</ImageButton.CommandParameter>

Desired Syntax
<Image CommandParameter="{conv:ItemToMenuItemConverter Menu=TOGGLE, MyView="{x:Reference optionsLayout}"}" x:TypeArguments="model:Item" />

ItemToMenuItemConverter is a Generic class, hence I am unable to achieve desired syntax. You can see the image now to see what the issue is.

please do NOT post code as images

@Jason I wanted to show a wholistic picture of what the requirement is. Had I posted this as chunks of code, it would not have that clarity.

It is not clear. I have difficulty in understanding your requirements, but, there are many opportunities for improvement. Have a look at creating markup extensions with bindable properties https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74319669/how-to-create-markup-extensions-having-bindable-properties. There see how several concepts (Binding/MultiBinding, markup extensions, IMultiValueConverter, BindableProperties are all merged into a single component)

@StephenQuan and IV, I have edited the question with code snippet. See if that helps.

I don't think you can use binding value converters without using binding.

You may try Create your own XAML markup extensions and consume it.

@LiqunShen-MSFT I am not sure how to achieve it. I can create a markup extension, where I can provide Menu and MyView properties, but not sure how can I provide the Type x:TypeArguments="model:Item" which will be used to generate the new ListViewMenuItem<T>()
