.NET MAUI Way to reuse constantly reused XAML Triggers?
Pretty new to MAUI dev. I have a situation in my MAUI app, where I need to change the text color of MANY labels based on a bool. So if the bool is true I want many of the labels to switch from white to grey color.
Currently, my solution is super repetitive. I want a simple thing that shows something like 1 / 4, where 1 and 4 are two variables. Maybe I'm approaching this completely wrong, but I haven't figured out any way to reduce this insanely long XAML code, to do something that I thing is super simple.
I just want those 3 characters to change colours when a bool flips! Keep in mind I need this type of color swap in many places throughout the app.
            <Label Text="{Binding SomeNumber}">
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                             Binding="{Binding SomeTriggerBool}"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Grey" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>
            <Label Text="/">
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                 Binding="{Binding SomeTriggerBool}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Grey" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>
            <Label Text="{Binding SomeOtherNumber}">
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                 Binding="{Binding SomeTriggerBool}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Grey" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>

Any way to go about this differently? Or at the very least reuse the trigger code? Without the triggers it looks like this:
            <Label Text="{Binding SomeNumber}" />
            <Label Text="/" />
            <Label Text="{Binding SomeOtherNumber}" />

This just screams to me that I'm doing something wrong.

I think in your case better to use Converter instead of triggers.
Example: Define a class like below
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is bool isTrue)
        return isTrue ? Colors.Grey : Colors.White;
        return Colors.White;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

Then add the converter to App.xaml so that you can use this anywhere in the app
 <local:BoolToColorConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" />

You can use Converter like this
 <Label Text="{Binding SomeNumber}" TextColor="{Binding SomeTriggerBool, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" />
    <Label Text="/" TextColor="{Binding SomeTriggerBool, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding SomeOtherNumber}" TextColor="{Binding SomeTriggerBool, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" />

know more here

That worked! Just needed to add a null check before the cast, and return white if value is null.

Great ! Updated answer accordingly.

Just for possible future people here, after learning about converters, I actually also updated the above to make an additional IMultiValueConverter That takes the two input numbers and outputs the converted string. So I can do it with one label (rather than 3), and one call to the color converter (rather than one each). Neat!

To avoid reinventing the wheel, have a look at the converters in CommunityToolkit.Maui such as their BoolToObjectConverter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/bool-to-object-converter

You can move your DataTrigger to a Style in your ResourceDictionary. If you want to make that the default style for Label you can drop the x:Key attribute.
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                 Binding="{Binding SomeTriggerBool}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Grey" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>


Thanks, This is a helpful tip. I was unaware styles could be triggered like this. Do you have any advice on when to use styles vs converters?

@AdamB initially, I started to write a lot of converters. I have since transitioned away to writing a lot of stuff using DataTriggers and bindings. Also I'm getting into markup extensions. For instance checkout one of my favourite markup extension implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74319669/how-to-create-markup-extensions-having-bindable-properties

Could you please give a sense of why you're moving away from converters?

There are a lot of converters already written, so, even less reason to write your own. Check out the converters in CommunityToolkit.Maui.
